# Why does 'zfs scrub' write to disk every 5 seconds?

Tags: zfs, scrub

My NAS is running zfs and does a scrub now and then.

When it runs it read all data (as expected), but it also writes a litte during the run (around 0.5%):

```
Device       rkB/s     wkB/s  %util
sda       13628.80     69.60  58.04
sdb       13625.60     73.60  59.48
sdc       13625.60     70.80  58.96
sdd       13625.60     68.40  58.24
sde       13625.60     69.60  60.00
```

This could be explained by other systems using it. But there are no systems using the NAS, and no user processes running on the server, that would access the NAS. Also the rate is constant for hours: Full read for 4.5 seconds followed by 0.5 seconds write. It is a fixed rythm: silence for 4.5 seconds, and then the DRRDRRD sound of seeking when it is writing.

But why does it write *anything* when there are no clients and nothing to correct?

I was under the impression that as long as all data are clean, consistent, and unchanged since last scrub, there would be no need to write any data.

Comment: a scrub will automatically repair errors if possible so is it possible that you have any errors on your pool?

Comment: The rate at which the data is changing - the ratio of writes/reads - is roughly 5 parts per thousand per second.  But if you take a snapshot then use watch you may be able to figure out which files are changing.

Comment: @jesse_b No errors. It does this every 5 seconds for the full 30 TB.

Comment: @CinaedSimson Not understood. The NAS is sitting idle when doing the scrub. No other system is using it.

Comment: If it never reads anything, it would never know if there was a problem. Monitoring requires reading. If 5 seconds is to short, change the zpool monitor time to as many seconds as you like. On my computer - when it's "empty" - in htop,  the uptime flucutates between roughtly 1-2 seconds. So 5 seconds - slightly over twice the flucation in uptime - is a safe starting point.

Comment: @CinaedSimson It reads alot: 65 MB/s. It does not *correct* anything and it not used by other clients (so when I say 'idle' I really mean: no other clients, no files are being touched). The 65 MB/s is for scrub only. And I perfectly understand why it reads. It is the *writing* I do not understand.

Comment: I have the same issue. The pool consists of 19 Mirrors of 2 disks (38 disks), 2 spares and a cache-ssd. I have zero activity (no writes, no reads) on this pool until i start a scrub. and from that moment on, the pool is _writing_ data to the disks. If i stop or pause the scrub there is no activity again. Multiple consecutive finished scrubs show the same behavior.

Comment: I have the same issue as @MartinSeitl. zpool is a mirror with three 16TB SATA  HDDs with one 256GB SSD as L2ARC. if I start a zpool scrub it does 60% writes and 40% reads. if I stop the scrub writes and reads stop. there are no other processes using the disk. atime=off on all file systems. tgx_sync process at 100% iowait. maybe it's upgrading the on-disk data format?

Comment: @JohnElliotV If it finishes a scrub, do you still see 60% write? Because I only see 0.5% write. I would be able to understand 60% for a single scrub with loads of rebuilding, but not on a second scrub.